# ElasticSearch document refresh=true does not appear to work

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

In order to speed up searches on our website, I have created a small elastic search instance which keeps a copy of all of the "searchable" fields from our database. It holds only a couple million documents with an average size of about 1KB per document. Currently (in development) we have just 2 nodes, but will probably want more in production.

Our application is a "primarily read" application - maybe 1000 documents/day get updated, but they get read and searched 10's of thousands of times/day.

Each document represents a case in a ticketing system, and the case may change status during the day as users research and close cases. If a researcher closes a case and then immediately refreshes his queue of open work, we expect the case to disappear from their queue, which is driven by a query to our Elastic Search instance, filtering by status. The status is a field in the case index.

The complaint we're getting is that when a researcher closes a case, upon immediate refresh of his queue, the case still comes back when filtering on "in progress" cases. If he refreshes the view a second or two later, it's gone.

In an effort to work around this, I added refresh=true when updating the document, e.g.
curl -XPUT 'https://my-dev-es-instance.com/cases/_doc/11?**refresh=true**' -d '{"status":"closed", ... }'

But still the problem persists.

Here's the response I got from the above request:

{"_index":"cases","_type":"_doc","_id":"11","_version":2,"result":"updated",**"forced_refresh":true**,**"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}**,"_seq_no":70757,"_primary_term":1}

The response seems to verify that the forced_refresh request was received, although it does say out of total 2 shards, 1 was successful and 0 failed. Not sure about the other one, but since I have only 2 nodes, does this mean it updated the secondary?

According to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-index_.html#index-refresh):
*To refresh the shard (not the whole index) immediately after the operation occurs, so that the document appears in search results immediately, the refresh parameter can be set to true. Setting this option to true should ONLY be done after careful thought and verification that it does not lead to poor performance, both from an indexing and a search standpoint. Note, getting a document using the get API is completely realtime and doesn’t require a refresh.*

Are my expectations reasonable? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache ? with `cases/_cache/clear?query=true` which would prevent cache response to be returned when you redo the search

Comment: @ExploZe that sounds a lot more expensive than refreshing a single shard, isn't it? Since the whole point of my elastic instance is to speed up searches, I fear that may have a much more negative impact on search times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing, I have concluded that my issue was due to application logic error, and not a problem with ElasticSearch. The refresh flag is behaving as expected. Apologies for the misinformation.